# How to get iPhone app to take good pictures using UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

In my iPhone app, I use `UIImagePickerController` to allow the users to take photos for use within the app. However, they always seem to come out blurry and/or unstable. What are some best practices when using `UIImagePickerController` to take photos on the iPhone, to make the pictures come out looking good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold the phone steady.

There isn't anything in the UIImagePickerController usage that can change how blurry the resulting images are.

Maybe you are doing something odd with the images afterwards that is causing the problem ?

Comment: Well, I have seen some iPhone camera apps which show a notice such as "stabilizing image," and I was wondering what if anything such apps are doing to stabilize it.